# Returning "last" value of chained promises in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angularjs-factory

I'm trying to do some geolocation and based on the coordinates, call a RESTful API that returns some data. Then I want to parse this data, and finally return it
I'm fairly new to angular.js and promises, therefore this code is kind of a mix of things I've seen through internet :D

I've made it all work but I'm missing the last step: returning the processed result array ("allSpots") to the original caller. What am I missing here?

```
.factory('wifiSpotFactory', function (WifinderModel, $q, $http) {

            function onGeolocationSuccess(position) {

            var url = 'http://localhost:34915/api/spots?latitude=' + position.coords.longitude + '&longitude=' + position.coords.latitude;

            $http.get(url).then(function (response) {

                var allSpots = [], data = response.data;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var newSpot = new WifinderModel.wifiSpot(data[i].id, data[i].name, data[i].password, data[i].address);
                    allSpots.push(newSpot);
                }

                return allSpots;

            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

        };

            var wifiSpotFactory = {
                loadNearSpots: function() {
                var geo_options = {
                    enableHighAccuracy: true,
                    maximumAge: 50000,
                    timeout: 30000
                };

                var deferred = $q.defer();

                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject, geo_options);

                return deferred.promise
                        .then(onGeolocationSuccess)
                        .then(function(allSpots) { return allSpots; });
            }
            };
            return wifiSpotFactory;
            } )
```

Then in the controller, how do I retrieve the value of the promise?

```
.controller('wifiListController', [
                '$scope', 'wifiSpotFactory', function ($scope, wifiSpotFactory) {
                    $scope.spots = wifiSpotFactory.loadNearSpots();
               }
])
```

Comment: So what does `WifinderModel.wifiSpot()` return - value or promise?

Comment: that returns a value -- an instance of the class

Comment: Mmm, in that case, Pankaj Parkar's solution looks like it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Callback` don't have an ability to return data, you should really used promise pattern there which would have ability to return data from promise. You `onGeolocationSuccess` is using callback pattern which seems `return data` but actually it doesn't.

You could solve the issue just by returning the promise from the `onGeolocationSuccess` method, for that you need to return `$http.get` object which already returns out a promise object. In `.then` of that function you would get `data` that has returned from API. From .then function you could return a `data` that will help you to follow the [**promise pattern**](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html).

**Code**

```
.factory('wifiSpotFactory', function(WifinderModel, $q, $http) {

  function onGeolocationSuccess(position) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:34915/api/spots?latitude=' + position.coords.longitude + '&longitude=' + position.coords.latitude;

    return $http.get(url).
    then(function(response) {
      var allSpots = [],
          data = response.data;
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var newSpot = new WifinderModel.wifiSpot(data[i].id, data[i].name, data[i].password, data[i].address);
        allSpots.push(newSpot);
      }
      return allSpots;

    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    });
  };

  var wifiSpotFactory = {
    loadNearSpots: function() {
      //..other code as is..to make solution cleaner removed that part.
      //return promise to follow promise chain
      return deferred.promise
      .then(onGeolocationSuccess)
      .then(function(allSpots) {
        return allSpots;
      });
    }
  };
  return wifiSpotFactory;
})
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('wifiListController', ['$scope', 'wifiSpotFactory', 
   function ($scope, wifiSpotFactory) {
       wifiSpotFactory.loadNearSpots().then(function(data){
           $scope.spots = data; //data will be available inside `.then` which promise resolve/reject
       });
   }
])
```

Comment: can you help me a bit with the full code? i've understood changing the onGeolocationSuccess but i'm not sure how the rest should be

Comment: doesn't work as expected:

loadNearSpots: function() {
                    
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);

                    deferred.promise
                            .then(onGeolocationSuccess)
                            .then(function(allSpots) { return allSpots; });                 


                }

Comment: @DanielPerez it should return promise like `return deferred.promise.then(function (position) { return onGeolocationSuccess(position);`

Comment: i'm still not getting it :(
if you could put the example for the loadNearSpots function as with the rest that'd help me a lot

Comment: i've updated the code to reflect the proposed changes

Comment: @DanielPerez see my update in code..returned promise which you missed..look at the commemt

Comment: thanks, I've added that. Now last step (see code), in the controller do I need to do something special? I mean, when I reach the end and want to retrieve the actual value (stop chaining), how can i do that?

Comment: @DanielPerez do look at my edit..no special thing.expect data in `promise.then` function.. That's It :)

Comment: I think i'm getting it now.
I've tried it and seems to be working, but there's a small problem. I've checked using the debugger, and the order of execution is not as expected. example: the $scope.spots = data gets called before the $http, therefore data is empty. but later on, the allSpots is populated. why is that?

Comment: @DanielPerez can't guess to much without seeing running code..Sorry to say that..

Answer (score 0):

Return the promise for chaining:

```
function onGeolocationSuccess(position) {
  var url = 'http://localhost:34915/api/spots?latitude=' + position.coords.longitude + '&longitude=' + position.coords.latitude;

  return $http.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    var allSpots = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var newSpot = new WifinderModel.wifiSpot(data[i].id, data[i].name, data[i].password, data[i].address);
      allSpots.push(newSpot);
    }

    return allSpots;

  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
};
```

Then the call can be:

```
deferred.promise
.then(onGeolocationSuccess)
.then(function(allSpots) { ... });
```

Comment: i've tried it but doesn't work for me. the "allSpots" on the last "then" is empty

Comment: i've updated the code to reflect the proposed changes